# how to use removeSheet and insertSheet on kendo Spreadsheet?

Tags: kendo-ui

I already read the documentation in

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet#methods-insertSheet

But on that link I didn't see the example for using this function.

Can someone give me the example for insertSheet method and removeSheet method?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you [look here yet](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/spreadsheet/overview)?

Comment: your link in the end, is redirect to my link.
thanks for your response mate.

Comment: Actually, it is to a different set of information than your link.

Answer (score 1):

```
//insertSheet:
var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").data("kendoSpreadsheet");
spreadsheet.insertSheet({name:'TEST'}); //you can set more than "name"

//removeSheet:
var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").data("kendoSpreadsheet");
var sheetWillBeDeleted = spreadsheet.sheetByName("TEST"); //you can also use sheetByIndex function to get the sheet by index.
spreadsheet.removeSheet(sheetWillBeDeleted);
```